# grabbing JSON data using coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion

I have a URL which when run in the browser, displays JSON data, since I am new to coldfusion, I am wondering, what would be a good way to
grab the data from the web browser? Later on I will be storing the individial JSON data into MySQL database, but I need to figure out step 1
which is grabbing the data.

Please advise.

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

1. You'll want to do a cfhttp request to load the external content.
2. Then you can use deserializeJSON to convert the JSON object into the appropriate cfml struct.

See the example Adobe gives in the [deserializeJSON documentation](https://learn.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/DeserializeJSON).

Answer (score 3):

Here is quick example:

```
<!--- Set the URL address. --->
<cfset urlAddress="http://ip.jsontest.com/">
<!--- Generate http request from cf --->
<cfhttp url="#urlAddress#" method="GET" resolveurl="Yes" throwOnError="Yes"/>
<!--- handle the response from the server ---> 
<cfoutput>
  This is just a string:<br />
  #CFHTTP.FileContent#<br />
</cfoutput>
<cfset cfData=DeserializeJSON(CFHTTP.FileContent)> 
This is object:<br />
<cfdump var="#cfData#">
Now you can do something like this:<br />
<cfoutput>#cfData.ip#</cfoutput>
```

Execute this source here http://cflive.net/